# Turning API data into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

sorry for the newbie question.

I'm new to using API's and I want to take the data from here
https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/prices/24615 (specifically the unit price under sells:) and display this in HTML.

This project will be using the unit price data across roughly 100 id's and I'd like to organize these numbers and run some basic math with them.

How can I go about this?

```
fetch('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/prices/24615')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  });
```

So far I can get the data into the console, but I'm not sure how to turn this into something I can work with.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is function in jQuery to make API calls, the following code makes you access api data,

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var info;
var whitelisted; 
var quantity;
$.get("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/prices/24615",function(obj){
    info = obj['id'];
    whitelisted = obj["whitlelisted"]
    quantity = obj.buys['quantity']
    $("#id1").html("id :"+info);
    $("#whitelist").html("whitelisted :"+whitelisted);
    $("#quan").html("quantity :"+quantity);
  });
});
```

for more info you could look into the following pen [link to the code](https://codepen.io/sai_yerni_akhil/pen/QZjpEe)

Comment: OP never mentioned jQuery

Comment: Since jQuery is also a part of JS Libraries, so the answer

Comment: Part of which Libraries ? jQuery is a library in itself, not a JS Standard or something

Comment: Hey this is working perfectly to pull the unit price data I need, however I'm not sure how to pull multiple ids from the api. I need to run math on the data across about a hundred items, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ignore these jerk moderators.

In your callback function, where you log myJson, edit your previously created html file,
like if you have a div, `<div id="myDiv"> </div>`, in the response function do something like this

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv")
myDiv.textContent = myJson.name
```

And your div will show the name from json, or whatever you need. Play around with these ideas and you'll get far